How to automatically move the cell selection based on the current new value displayed in Datagridview, without clicking on a cell
In C#, how to automatically move the cell selection(no cell click event) to the current new value displayed in datagridview column. The datagridview refreshes data every minute.
The sample below has displayed a new value under "Tag" header column with a value of "6" and the cell selection goes to the new index value, then automatically pass the value to a textbox control.

I tried this line to test, but the condition should be dynamic based from latest added tag value. When i increment to 7 and saved to database, the displayed datagridview will refresh to display tag 7 and automatically gets
highlighted.
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_pat_labopd_lst.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "6")
                    {                            
                        //To select the row
                        row.Selected = true;
                    }
                }


You would need to share some minimal example of your code, and what you have tried that did not work.

The sample below has displayed a new value under "Tag" header column with a value of "6" and just how did this happen?? By user input or automagically?

from user input in another windows form and was saved to database.

Well in that case this window should call a refresh/update function/event on this window, no? One (recommended) way to write this is a delegate.
